# Where does one place binary level data

Tags: xna, binary, filestream

I'm using a filestream with binary data and I don't want to put my binary in  "c:\test.bin." It seems so amateur. Where is a good place to put or better yet where can a programmatically find the xna content folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your binaries into the Content project. Add your files there, mark them as "Copy If Newer" under "Copy To Output Directory" so that they deploy into your Content directory during runtime, and also mark them as "Content" or "None" under "Build Action", otherwise they will try to compile as xnb's (and likely fail).

Use this to programmatically access them:

[`TitleContainer.OpenStream("Content/test.bin");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.titlecontainer.openstream.aspx)

This returns a `Stream`, pass it into a `BinaryReader` like so:

```
using (var r = new BinaryReader(TitleContainer.OpenStream("Content/test.bin")))
{
    r.ReadByte();
    //....
}
```